# How to sort KeyValue in dictionary and return a string

Tags: swift3

Say, I have the following url.

I store the keyValues in a dictionary

```
let strURL = "https://www.x.com/?d=1&a=2&b=3&c=4&nbr=1234567890"
let items = URLComponents(string:strURL)?.queryItems
var KeyValues:[String:String] = [:]

items?forEach {
    item in KeyValues[item.name] = item.value
}
```

Problem : how to sort it and output a string from the KeyValues such that

```
 string = "a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&nbr=1234567890"
```

Thanks

Comment: Consider that a query string behaves like a dictionary where a specific order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
let sorted = KeyValues.map { $0 }.sorted { $0.key < $1.key }
let result = sorted.dropFirst().reduce("\(sorted.first!.key)=\(sorted.first!.value)") { (result, kvp) -> String in
    result + "&\(kvp.key)=\(kvp.value)"
}
```

We first turn the dictionary into a `[(String, String)]` then we sort it according to the key.

Then, we `reduce` the sorted array to join the keys and values together.

Comment: Compiler error : use of unresolved identifier 'key'.  What I need to do?

Comment: @MilkBottle it worked for me though... Try the edited answer,